# Connect wordpress and Microsoft Dynamics 365 via API

Tags: wordpress, api, dynamic, dynamics-crm, wordpress-rest-api

We wish to connect a Wordpress site to an API. We have a JSON file, that lists all of the functions and connection to the API, and this API
connects to Microsoft Dynamics 365.

In the API it exists functionality to save points, authentication for logging in and for checking a random winner when logging in. This
means it consist of get and set functions.

So the issue is how are we going to connect the API to the wordpress site? The wordpress at the moment exists on a multi-site. Have anybody done this before, connected Microsoft Dynamics 365 via api to a wordpress site? Or does anybody have a good solution or example for this? If so, please help me :) It should be easy, but its not, when we do not have done this before.
If needed more info, please let me know, and i will provide it.

Thank you all.

Comment: https://alexacrm.com/plugin/

Comment: Hi @GuidoPreite thanks, you started a thought process here. Let me add more info, we want the user to login via phonenumber and password. Have you seen a wordpress site that does this?